# Google cloud Storage Class to be mentioned in Lifecycle Policy -Standard or Regional

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-storage, google-cloud-storage

From google cloud official documentation I can see that both Standard storage class and Regional storage classes are the same: [https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes#:~:text=Regional%20storage%3A%20Equivalent%20to%20Standard%20storage%2C%20except%20Regional%20storage%20can%20only%20be%20used%20for%20objects%20stored%20in%20regions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes#:%7E:text=Regional%20storage%3A%20Equivalent%20to%20Standard%20storage%2C%20except%20Regional%20storage%20can%20only%20be%20used%20for%20objects%20stored%20in%20regions).

I need to implement a lifecycle policy to delete objects based on the storage class. while mentioning the storage class which one I should specify? is it Standard or Regional? If I mention Regional in the policy will it remove the objects created as Standard as well?

Comment: Hi @ANANTH I have provided an answer below.please check and let me know if the below suggestions were helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regional storage is equivalent to Standard storage, except Regional storage can only be used for objects stored in regions.

However, the Standard (which can be either Regional or Multi-Regional)The usual approach is to select Standard, where you can opt to have your bucket in a specific single Google Cloud Region or stored across multiple Regions. This works really well in different scenarios since you get a highly performant and highly available storage.

As mentioned in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle#:%7E:text=For%20buckets%20in%20a%20region%2C%20the%20new%20storage%20class%20cannot%20be%20Multi%2DRegional%20storage.%20For%20buckets%20in%20a%20multi%2Dregion%20or%20dual%2Dregion%2C%20the%20new%20storage%20class%20cannot%20be%20Regional%20storage.), For buckets in a region, the new storage class cannot be Multi-Regional storage. For buckets in a multi-region or dual-region, the new storage class cannot be Regional storage.

you can specify the Standard storage class in your lifecycle policy. This will ensure that the policy applies to all objects, regardless of the storage class.